# Click "OK" on Error Loading Extension pop up using python webbot

Tags: python, popup, webbot

Trying to click "OK" on a pop up using a webbot script in order to pull down a file from a website. On one machine the following code worked:

```
from webbot import Browser
import time
import keyboard
import threading

def push_ok_button():
    keyboard.press_and_release('enter')

class CustomThread(threading.Thread):
    def init(self, function, start_delay_seconds=None):
    threading.Thread.init(self)
    self.function = function
    self.start_delay_seconds = start_delay_seconds

def run(self):
    if self.slart_delay_seconds:
        time.sleep(self.start_delay_seconds)
    self.function()

push_ok_thread = CustomThread(push_ok_button, start_delay_seconds=5)
push_ok_thread.start()

web = Browswer()
push_ok_thread.join()
web.go_to('website.com')
```

On my machine I rec'd the following error:

```
TypeError:___init___() got an unexpected keyword argument 'start_delay_seconds'
```

I've also tried web.click('enter') and web.click('OK') but those fail as well.

Comment: for init use `def ___init___(your parameters...)`

Comment: THANK YOU!

Needed the __ on either side of the init. Thanks Daraan!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daraan commented above that I needed to add underscores on either side of my init, now the "OK" button is pressed.